# Is subscription lies in any region (like Topic) in Google Pub Sub

Tags: publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I am working on project which using google pub sub for transfer of messages, I have seen the Topic created in pub sub should specify regions (if we define multiple region, the message will store only nearby region of publisher). I have question regarding this.

1. Is there is any replication in between regions for Topic for storing message.
2. Is subscription also lies in any region which is created on Topic.

Comment: PubSub is a global and serverless product. You haven't to worry about the location, replication and so on. You have SLAs that guaranty you a level of confidence in the service. If you have requirement, or concerns, about data sovereignty, you can define a region for the topic and the subscription. Until then, you have to trust the service, replication and its internal optimization (that I don't know!)

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Pub/Sub is a global service. What that means is that topics and subscriptions are not tied to a specific region. Publishers can publish messages to topics in any region and subscribers can connect in any region (the same or different as the publishers) and receive the messages published to the topic via subscriptions.

The ability to specify regions for storage in Cloud Pub/Sub is a feature called [message storage policy](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/resource-location-restriction). The intention of this feature is to allow you specify which regions messages can or cannot be stored (though they still transit through other regions if subscribers are attached in those other regions). This allows one to place restrictions on data storage to, for example, comply with local laws.

If using the global Pub/Sub endpoint, publishers and subscriber connect to the network-nearest region to send or receive messages. When running publishers or subscribers on GCP, this means they will connect to the region where those resources are located. If using [regional endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/service_apis_overview#service_endpoints), then the publisher or subscriber connects to the region specified. However, even when using regional endpoints, the service is still global in that messages published in different regions to the same topic are still all available to subscribers using the same single subscription tied to that topic.

Messages are not replicated across regions when published. They are [replicated to three zones within a region](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/architecture#data_plane_-_the_life_of_a_message), though. If subscribers are located in a different region than the messages were published, then Cloud Pub/Sub routes messages across the regions to deliver them to the subscribers, wherever they are currently running.

Comment: Thanks Kamal for your reply, but if any region down due to any reason, then subscriber will get the message or not.

Comment: I have one more question, subscriber is listener which is consuming a message and can you please help me in understanding the subscription. Is subscription tied with topic is also lies in a same region or subscription doesn't lie in any region?

Comment: please provide your input on the above comments.

Comment: As I said: " What that means is that topics **and subscriptions** are not tied to a specific region." If a region is down, then subscribers in that region may not receive messages during that time. Any messages published into that region may be temporarily unavailable as well. If there are subscribers in other regions and messages to consume from other regions, then those subscribers will get those messages. If not, then consumption will continue once the region is back up.